# ESLint custom rule - no spaces for property access

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, rules

I've configured my `ESLint` for node project with

```
'no-multi-spaces'  : ['error'],
```

rule. It automatically fixes `object  .property` to `object .property`

```
object.
property
```

to

```
object 
  . property
```

, but I'm not satisfied with it. I want `object.property` as a  fix result.

Is there any ideas which rule should be applied?

Comment: You can try `no-whitespace-before-property` and `dot-location`

Comment: @IVOGELOV, can you please change rule-names to rules?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/dot-location and https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-whitespace-before-property